# zstd: can't stat web.log.* : No such file or directory -- ignored

Tags: grep, zstd

I can't seem to find help on using `zstdgrep` correctly. I thought it works like ordinary `grep`, but I am not getting what I want. I have several subfolders that have files in the format of `webserver.log.YYYY-MM-DD.zst`. These are archives of logs over some time.

I want to find `my log message text` in any of them. I tried these:

```
zstdgrep -r "my log message text" webserver.log.*.zst
zstdgrep "my log message text" webserver.log.*.zst
zstdgrep -r -e"my log message text" --include webserver.log.*.zst
```

But these all give me:

```
zstd: can't stat http.log.*.zst : No such file or directory -- ignored
```

The last one prints:

```
zstd: can't stat --include : No such file or directory -- ignored
zstd: can't stat http.log.*.zst : No such file or directory -- ignored
```

So it seems the `--include` is not supported or I misplaced it.

I need to find particular exact string match in zst files in multiple subfolders. What am I doing wrong?